# Term for the largest shareholder of a public stock

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

In Turkish stock market there is a specific term for the largest owner of a publicly traded stock, "tahtaci", which is someone or some corporation who can control the price of the shares by holding a very large position and having a lot of cash. For example s/he can order a sell with a huge number of shares so no other investor can match to buy, which stops the price from going up, even if the company is doing good.

Is this situation also common in US or other markets and is there a specific term for it in English?

Comment: "Private equity" companies seek to hold such large positions that they gain influence or control of stock companies. "Private equity" operations are really the true history of WB and so there are mini-Buffets.

Comment: Mutual funds usually don't seek influence in stock companies that they hold. Pension funds sometimes have active voting position.